# Fonts characters specifications

Tags: opencv, fonts, ocr, tesseract, specifications

I wonder if there is some specifications about characters of current font - width,height,area of the character or some way to calculate this according font size and font family. I am using tesseract 3.02 and I am finding symbols size and font family, but now I want using also openCV to extract all points from the image according this font family and size(becouse tesseract is not good enough in detecting sequences of points/dots), but what I`m actually finding with OpenCV is bounding rectangles or edges of the dots, and the font size only gives me information of this:

[image]

Also there is significant difference between area of the dots(or characters) of different font families, and also the height and width of the dot - for example size 72 of Calibre vs size 72 of Trebuchet MS.
   I want also to ask where can I see which fonts do tesseract 3.02 use for detection(if it is impossible in another way, I want to describe characters  specifications by hand) and what each column in the file "eng.cube.size" mean. Summary I need C++ library or tool which can give me detailed information about fonts according given font family and font size, in other words - open .ttf file and give me info.